# Fetching particular rows of a csv file where date matches as entered by user?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime64, csvreader

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFcg0.png)i have a csv file like

```
Slot                   object
Name                   object
Plate                  object
Date_of_reg    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I was working on a parking program that can give person data based on given date
I took date from user as shown below:

```
inputDate =input("Enter the date in format 'dd-mm-yy':")
y=datetime.datetime.strptime(inputDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
c=np.datetime64(y)
```

now if i am trying to read and print data from my csv file i get empty columns even though i have date

```
with open('parking.csv', mode='r') as park:
    park_reader =csv.DictReader(park)
    for row in park_reader:

                    


                     //some code that didn't work\\
```

I dunno what to do next any help would be hugely appreciated :)
remember i only want to print rows where the input date matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty database was being created as np.datetime64 is no longer comparable to datetime.datetime so that waa the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv('parking.csv')
df['Date_of_reg'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_reg'])

input_date = input("Enter the date in format 'dd-mm-yy':")
input_date = dt.datetime.strptime(input_date, '%d-%m-%y')  # NB: non-capitalized 'y' if you want year without century padding

filtered_df = df[df['Date_of_reg'] == input_date]
print(filtered_df)
```

Comment: the above code gave me keyError : 'Date_of_reg' dont know what might be causing it

Comment: Then your column is probably called something else than 'Date_of_reg' - Try `print(df.columns)` to see your column names

Comment: Columns: [Slot, Name, Plate, Date_of_reg]
    Index: []

Comment: here's what i got

Comment: Ok not really sure what is going on without seeing what your data looks like

Comment: Either that or make a small example of your data that reproduces the error https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thats empty? It only seems to have one line and no column headers. Also, please open it in notepad, not in excel.

Comment: so i sorted everything that is header now exists and my data wont override it but still the same problem even after using the code that you suggested..

Comment: I sorted it all out and THANKS A LOT BUDDY I MEAN IT and sorry for being ANNOYING the empty dataframe was being created as numpy.datetime64 is no longer comparable to datetime.datetime object so i converted datetime to np.datetime64 THANKS AGAIN :))